# Volatility swaps hedging

Tags: implied-volatility, stochastic-calculus, volatility-smile, volatility-surface, variance-swap

I have heard that traders use a straddle to hedge volatility swaps (in the FX context), although I could not figure out the specifics. Is this type of hedge used in practice? And if yes, how does it work? Is there an approximation formula that could be written down to justify such a hedging strategy? This is a question about VOLATILITY swaps, not variance swaps.

Comment: An ATM straddle can be used to hedge volatility, but the problem is it will not stay ATM forever; as the price of the underlying drifts away from the current value, the Gamma will decrease and it wont be as effective a hedge. You can close the position and open up another straddle at current levels from time to time, but that adds transaction costs and some inaccuracy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this question seems Taylor-made for me, I shall resist promoting my own work and refer you instead to Carr and Lee's seminal paper [Robust replication of volatility derivatives](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Erl/rrvd.pdf).

Basically what the paper demonstrates is that although initially you could start with a simple straddle (ATM is not always the best choice, but that's another matter), once there is realised volatility a single straddle won't do. To replicate the volswap you'll need to continuously rebalance a strip of options whether you follow Carr and Lee's or my method.

The reason the aforementioned methods use a continuously rebalanced strip of options is because they try to be as model-free as possible, ie to be approximately right for a very large class of stochastic volatility models.

Hence, if you only want to use single options to hedge a volswap, your best route would be to choose a particular model, do a numerical simulation to calculate the sensitivity of a particular option and the volswap to the instantaneous volatility, and match these sensitivities by choosing an appropriate notional for the option.

In this case you could think you're exactly right, but then you are exposed to model-risk and so you're still only approximately right. But at least you save on transaction costs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I recall Carr gave a talk about this paper in Bloomberg Quant seminar, around that time. What a loss. One should further take a look at [Peter Friz and Jim Gatheral. Valuation of volatility derivatives as an inverse problem](https://doi.org/10.1080/14697680500362452) accessible on sci-hub.

Comment: @DimitriVulis Yes great loss indeed. The only well known quant who happily wasted time talking to me, and I'm sure to others in the field as well, once in a while. He was a very modest person.

Comment: Carr was a wonderful person and is greatly missed. Anyways, the OP should further look at https://doi.org/10.1002/WILM.10566 and other papers listed in https://www.semanticscholar.org/author/Frido-Rolloos/119978388